# Is $(this) required with the "standard" plugin pattern of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been following the [standard](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) way of creating jQuery plugins. In particular, the bit about not polluting the fn namespace. But, I came across some strange things where it violates it's own "never use `$(this)` rule.

```
var methods = {
 init : function( options ) {

   return this.each(function(){

     var $this = $(this), //HERE
         data = $this.data('tooltip'),
         tooltip = $('<div />', {
           text : $this.attr('title')
         });

     // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
     if ( ! data ) {

       /*
         Do more setup stuff here
       */

       $(this).data('tooltip', {
           target : $this,
           tooltip : tooltip
       });

     }
   });
 },
```

Is reevaluating `this` essential in this particular case? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Inside the method, `this` refers to the jQuery object that was used to call the plugin, but you are using `each` to loop through those elements. In the callback for `each`, `this` referes to a DOM element from the jQuery object, so you need to create a new jQUery object for each element to use jQuery methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `each` loop, `this` is the DOM element so yes `$(this)` is essential to use jquery methods on it.

The «never use `$(this)`» rule concerns what you return. A method returning `$(this)` instead of `this` would break pointers like the `prevObject` property that is used by the jquery `end` method.